# Jackson field value with default quotation marks

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there some way to tell Jackson to Serialize all numbers with quotation marks? I am working with generated objects from a webservice so I can't add annotations.

For example I would like that this field

```
BigDecimal value;
```

gets serialized by default to

```
"value": "0"
```

instead of

```
"value": 0
```

Comment: Does it matter? In javascript you have the benefit of type coercion.

Comment: I am creating a webservice to be used by an ipad app. I need it to be a string

Comment: What comes as a response is always a string basically. I'm not familiar with how the iOS utilities handles JSON responses but I can't imagine it's a problem. If the value is an integer so be it. If the application needs a string it's the application's responsibility to handle that IMHO.

Comment: I completely agree it should be the app's responsibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Custom Serializer for BigDecimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a custom serializer. But I also found out that jackson has MixIn annotations which allow annotations on third-party classes http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations